# what is the port number of the server on the android mobile phone not on AVD to can allow client to connect?

Tags: android, sockets, sdk

I had succeeded in developing this on AVD through eclipse but i want to do it on the mobile android phones.

But they can't connect to each other while testing on mobiles.

So, my question is "how to set the ports"
On AVD's , i gived the server port no. 2000 while client is connected to 1000, so i had redirected the ports through "telnet localhost" but on android phones i can't do this "telnet"

So, please help how to set IP and ports while developing on phones not virtual devices.
Thanks

Comment: Use te same port number for both. The client should use the ip of the server.

Comment: Yes I did this but it didn't work
what about the IP

Comment: If you want help you should come more to the point. So explain your setup better. Why are you asking 'what about the IP'? What do you mean by that?